# Showing time of the video frame on hover over seek bar

Tags: angularjs, html, html5-video

I am trying to show the time on hover of seek bar of a html5 video. ( similar to how youtube does it).
I have tried to use the timeupdate event on the video as below but looks like there is more to it.

```
        <script>
    function myFunction(event) {
        // The currentTime property 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.currentTime;
      var video = event;
      video.addEventListener('progress', function() {
        var bufferedEnd = video.buffered.end(video.buffered.length - 1);
        var duration =  video.duration.toFixed(1);
        alert(duration);
        if (duration > 0) {
          document.getElementById('buffered-amount').style.width = ((bufferedEnd / duration)*100) + "%";
        }
      });

      //  display the current and remaining times
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
      //  Current time  
      var vTime = video.currentTime;
      var vLength = video.duration.toFixed(1);
      document.getElementById("curTime").textContent = vTime.toFixed(1);
      document.getElementById("vRemaining").textContent = (vLength - vTime).toFixed(1);
    }, false);

   }
  </script>
```

html:

```
 <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
  <div class="buffered">
   <span id="buffered-amount"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
   <span id="progress-amount"></span>
  </div>

  <p>Playback position: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <p>Current Time: <span id="curTime"></span></p>
  <p>Remaining Time: <span id="vRemaining"></span></p>
```

I did try to understand multiple posts but did not find a solution. 
Do I need to use onmouseover event instead? How do I calculate the time of the video frame when the user positions the mouse on the slider?

Comment: Could you provide an example of code? It will be much easier to help you with your problem.

Comment: Sure. Looks like I forgot to give the snippet. Let me edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a custom controls something like this:
Using the width of the controls div and `video.duration` to calculate the new time.

Hope this helps!

```js
window.onload = function(){
  controls.innerText = ''
function getNewTime(e){
  return e.clientX / controls.clientWidth * video.duration
 }
 controls.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  controls.innerText = (getNewTime(e).toFixed(2))
 })
 
 controls.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  video.currentTime = getNewTime(e)
 })
    
    video.addEventListener('click', function(){
        video.play()
      }
    )
    }
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  background:black;
 }
 #wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
 }
 #video{
  flex:1;
  height:calc(100vh - 32px);
 }
 #controls{
  height:32px;
  background:red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Custom Video Control</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='wrapper'>
  <video id='video' src='http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'></video>
  <div id='controls'>loading</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

edit: to clarify my answer

If you look at the code: `e.clientX / controls.clientWidth * video.duration` you will see that

- `e.clientX` is the current x position of your mouse on the controls rectangle.
- `controls.clientWidth` is the total width of the controls rectangle.
- `video.duration` is the total time of the video.

so if I would put my mouse on the end of the of the rectanlge. I would get 100% of the video duration. and in the beginning I would get 0%. if I would put my mouse at exactly in the middle I would get exactly the time of the middle of the video.

with `video.currentTime` I can change the current time of the video so that the frame is exactly the right frame of the time.

Comment: Does this capture the correct video frame based on the time? Or is it just a random time change on mouse over ? Please explain.

Comment: I edit my answer to hopefully clarify my answer. It does capture the correct video frame based on the time if you use this.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Close to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `controls` attribute. You will get similar *control bar* that is present on *YouTube* videos.

> If this attribute is present, Gecko will offer controls to allow the user to control video playback, including volume, seeking, and pause/resume playback.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

**Example in code.pen:**(wait for video to load)
http://codepen.io/mikemoney/pen/QdQvXY

**Example on SO:** (wait for video to load)

```html
<video src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_1mb.mp4" autoplay poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1iGy1Rp93o4/maxresdefault.jpg" controls width="480">
</video>
```

Comment: The examples don't seem to have what I am looking for:  time that dynamically changes based on where the user hovers the cursor on the horizontal axis of the video

Comment: "I am trying to show the time on hover of seek bar of a html5 video. ( similar to how youtube does it)." Even if my answer wasn't exactly what you'd expect, there's no need to vote down. I provided you a working example as well as pointed you to the documentation.

Comment: I did not vote you down, had just left a comment to your answer. I have corrected to not give -1 to your solution now. I appreciate your time and effort in trying to help me solve my problem. Thanks!